# How to repeat ul and div after every 9th li

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to repeat `<div>`and `<ul>` after every 9th record. But not getting exact result. Please help to sort out the issue.

```
<div class="col1">
<div class="mylist">
    <ul>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
        <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>  

<?php 
                    $args1 = array(
                    'post_type' => 'newser',
                    'orderby'   => 'id', 
                    'order'     => 'ASC',
                    'tax_query' => array(
                        array(
                        'taxonomy' => 'service',
                        'field' => 'id',
                        'terms' => $term_id
                         )
                      )
                    );
                    $query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 ); 
                    $counter = 1;
                    while ($query1->have_posts()) : $query1->the_post(); 

                    ?>

                    <div class="col1">
                        <div class="mylist">
                            <ul>


                             <li class="test<?php echo $counter; ?>"><a href="#">
                             <?php the_title(); ?>
                            </a>
                                </li>
                            <?php  
                            if($counter % 9 == 0)
                            {
                                echo '</ul></div></div><div class="col-sm-4"><div class="list-part"><ul>';
                            }
                            ?>

                          <!--  </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->

                <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Where's the code you're using?

Comment: upload your full code

Comment: can you add your expected result/output?

Comment: How about that one? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="col1">
    <div class="mylist">
        <ul>
            <?php
            for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
                ?>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"><?= $i ?></a></li>
                <?php if ($i % 9 == 0 && $i > 0) { ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="mylist">
                <ul>
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>    
            <?php if ($i % 9 != 0 || !$i) { ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div> 
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this type of code..

```
<div class="col1">
    <div class="mylist">
        <ul>
        <?php 
        for($i=1;$i<=20;$i++){
            if($i==9){
                echo '</ul></div></div>';
                echo '<div class="col1"><div class="mylist"><ul>';
            }
            echo '<li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>';
        }
        ?>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That will echo the end and start tags only after the 8th element (not the 9th as specified), and not after the 18th, 27th etc.. You would have to use modulo `%`, as the OP already does.

Answer (score 0):

Hey if you are doing php so below code will work for you:

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 180; $i++) {
    ?>
    <div class="col1">
        <div class="mylist">
            <ul>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <li class="test1"><a href="#"></a></li>
                <?php if ($i % 9 == 0) { ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div> 
        <div class="col1">
            <div class="mylist">
                <ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>    
    <?php } ?>    

    ?>
```

I think that will be work.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a for-loop that has conditions for the various special conditions, e.g. handling the first element (need the starting `<ul>`), every ninth position (your question), and the last element (need the closing `</ul>`).

```
for($i=1; $i<=$counter; $i++){
    if($i==1){
        echo '<ul><li>gdgdfgdfg</li>';
    } else if($i%9==0 && $i>1 && $i<$counter){
        echo '<li>gdgdfgdfg</li></ul><ul>';
    } else if($i==$counter){
        echo '<li>gdgdfgdfg</li></ul>';
    } else{
        echo '<li>gdgdfgdfg</li>';
    }
}
```